# How do I ignore property x of exported class expression may not be private or protected?

Tags: typescript

I'm using an external library and extending its main class to override a specific method, which returns another class. That other class has protected/private methods that I don't need to access directly. I tried to just ignore the error with @ts-ignore and @ts-expect-error, but the error persists, perhaps because it is caused by code deeper in the library, so I can't just ignore the next line.

Is there a way for me to extend this class without the error? Or, is there a way to ignore this error completely since I don't need the private/protected members?

```js
export class PocketbaseService extends Pocketbase {
    constructor(baseUrl: string) {
        super(baseUrl);
    }

    /* error text is: Property 'authResponse' of exported class expression may not be 
    private or protected.ts(4094)
    Property '_getFullList' of exported class expression may not be private or 
    protected.ts(4094)
    Property '_getList' of exported class expression may not be private or 
    protected.ts(4094)
    etc
    */
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore TS error #4904, doesn't affect us, unclear why we can't expect or ignore it
    collection(collection: Collections) {
        return super.collection(collection);
    }
}
```